# Expectation of dipole is vector in x direction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

So I am asked to find a state $|\Psi(t)\rangle$ in terms of the hydrogen wave functions, such that the expectation of the dipole operator -$e\hat r$ is a vector in the x direction.

I am not completely sure how to approach this.  I am having a hard time visualing what this is trying to say in a sense of wavefunctions.  I know what a dipole is, but I would expect the dipole moment for hydrogen states to be a vector in two directions.  Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: It sounds like you want $\left \langle \Psi \right | \hat{y} \left | \Psi \right \rangle$ to be zero. Same thing for the $\hat{z}$ operator. But non-zero for $\hat{x}$. Is this right?

Comment: Yes.  I have been trying to figure out a combination of states to do this, because $\langle \Psi \hat r|\Psi\rangle$ is zero for an eigenstate

Comment: If i recall correctly, the fact that $\hat r$ is an odd function is relevant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that spherical harmonics [also have a cartesian representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_spherical_harmonics#l_.3D_1.5B1.5D) I think you're pretty much sorted. For example, what about $\frac{Y^1_1 + Y^{-1}_1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: But I want a position vector in the x direction.  How will spherical harmonics help out?

Comment: did you check out the link?

Comment: Yes I did.  I ended it up figuring it out.  That combination gave me something in the z direction, so a simple rotation operator fixed it!  Thanks